# How to set targeted Modules for specific URL in AppEngine + Java

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, gae-module

In Backends base app engine project(Java) i was doing

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("userou-queue");
TaskOptions objTskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/backendsURL/")
.countdownMillis(2000)
.header("Host", BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("backendname"))
.method(Method.GET);
queue.add(objTskOptions);
```

But now for Modules How can i target a specific Module for my specific URL.

Please help me.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing -- is this link helpful for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From App Engine documentation:

> The following code sample demonstrates how to create a push task
>   addressed to instance 1 of a module named backend1, using the target
>   directive:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.Queue;
import com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueFactory; 
import static com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Builder.*;
import com.google.appengine.api.backends.*;

// ...
queue.add(withUrl("/path/to/my/worker").param("key", key).header("Host",
BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("backend1", 1));
```

Comment: But, Backends are deprecated. And BackendServiceFactory is also deprecated.

Comment: The [Modules API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/package-summary) provides similar capabilities.

Comment: This is the currently recommended way to target modules from Tasks - this App Engine doc page was updated on October 27, 2014 - just three weeks ago.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. I get "IllegalStateException: Tried to get local address of unknown backend". Testing now but i think ModulesService needs to be used. At least i hope, because i don't know how else to do this with Modules and task queue in the dev server. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing

Comment: If you cannot find your backend, it does not mean that the answer is wrong :)  Anyway, try to use the queue configuration as Peter suggested.

Comment: The question asked about Modules, which is the upgrade of Backends. This would never work for the user, because their are no backends when using modules. Changing to the ModulesService didn't work for me, but others have said it does. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10954&q=label%3AComponent-TaskQueue&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: It works for the OP. And I did say that using Peter's suggestion is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `target` parameter in the queue definition file: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue#target

Comment: For this i have to create different queue for each module.