# 'com.google.appengine.api.backends.BackendService' is deprecated alternative

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client

'com.google.appengine.api.backends.BackendService' is deprecated less... 
This inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope. I am getting this error when I am using BackendService for Google. Is there any alternatives to replace this?

```
import com.google.appengine.api.backends.BackendService;
BackendService backendsApi = BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone facing this issue, you can actually just do it without declaring BackendService. For example when used in a queue:

```
 queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/test")
                        .param("testing","a")
.header("Host",BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("backend")));
```

answer can also be found here [How to set targeted Modules for specific URL in AppEngine + Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009501/how-to-set-targeted-modules-for-specific-url-in-appengine-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can just look it up in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/backends/BackendService) of `com.google.appengine.api.backends.BackendService` where it says:

> This API is deprecated and has been replaced by [ModulesService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService). Please update your code as soon as possible. See the modules documentation for more information: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting

So just use `ModulesService` from now on and convert it via the [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting) mentioned in the docs.